# How to use AMQP with Apache Camel and Apache CXF?

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, amqp, qpid

Greetings all
I am using Apache Camel and Apache CXF in this example:

http://camel.apache.org/better-jms-transport-for-cxf-webservice-using-apache-camel.data/cxfcamelexample.zip

and I want to use AMQP instead of JMS but I don't know the configuration,
also I need to change the version of QPID client
if anyone can help, this will be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the unit test of camel-amqp component?
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-amqp/

Comment: what about using it via xml bean injection like the jms <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
 </bean> <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
  <property name="useMessageIDAsCorrelationID" value="true" />
 </bean>

Comment: The component uses apache qpid, so check their doc how to create a qpid connection factory, you use in the spring XML file.

Comment: what doc, can you please give me a little more guide , and what is the use of the above link?

Comment: the link is for unit tests, so take a look at those source to see how it test the AMQP component. Maybe that helps you understand how to use it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the AMQP component which is developed based on Qpid project is matured to a stage where it can work succesfully. There is no good POC supported for this component either. Check http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/jira-Created-CAMEL-2872-camel-amqp-not-receiving-messages-td511735.html

Comment: I've posted an alternative Camel AMQP component at https://github.com/Bluelock/camel-spring-amqp

Comment: Good point. I had some real struggle working with the QPID java client together with RabbitMQ server (using the same AMQP version) for tasks that are just a little bit more complex than connecting.